# a generic version of an F# function is causing invalid IL?

Tags: f#, mono, generics, il

So I've written a little binary search function (not that I need to, but just because I can), and when I make it specific to strings or to integers, for example, it works well.  When I attempt to use a generic type signature, I start getting exceptions.

A copy of the function using a generic type, `'a`:

```
let search (needle : 'a) (haystack: 'a array) : int = 
    let length = Array.length haystack

    if Array.length haystack <= 0
    then -1
    else
        let bottom = 0
        let top = Array.length haystack - 1

        let rec search' (needle : 'a) (haystack: 'a array) (bottom:int) (top:int) : int = 
            if bottom = top
            then if needle = haystack.[top] then top else -1
            else
                let middle = (uint32 top + uint32 bottom) >>> 1 |> int  // avoid an overflow

                if needle <= haystack.[middle]
                then search' needle haystack bottom middle
                else search' needle haystack (middle+1) top

        search' needle haystack bottom top
```

When this is called, I get the following:

```
System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in FSI_0019:search'@921-13<a> (a,a[],int,int): IL_0000: br        IL_0005
  at FSI_0019.search[String] (System.String needle, System.String[] haystack) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at <StartupCode$FSI_0023>.$FSI_0023.main@ () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Stopped due to error
```

Am I doing something wrong?  (Again, when I use `string` or `int` instead of `'a`, everything works...)

**Edit:**

I've compiled Mono 2.9 or so, and this function then works in FSI.  Now, to wait for Debian and Ubuntu to upgrade... :D

Comment: What version of Mono are you using? A few similarly looking bugs were fixed in Mono 2.8...

Comment: Version 2.6.7...  (Even Ubuntu 11.04 includes 2.6.7 right now, apparently.  I'm in 10.10.)  Hmmmmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono bug.
Before, I had a code that does not work on `fsi` but works compiled.

EDIT: It's confirmed that that code doesnt work on `fsi`, but works with compiled by `fsc`.

Comment: Hmm, yes, running from MonoDevelop via the Run menu must use `fsc`, because that works...

Comment: Log the bug here: http://mono-project.com/Bugs. The thing to mention is that the bug is in "Reflection.Emit" (the path that fsi uses) and not the Mono compiler itself.

Comment: Hmm.  I'll try again tomorrow, but right now bugzilla.novell.com doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (running FSI on .NET 4.0).  Perhaps it's a Mono bug?